# How can I launch my local html file which in my workspace, on a vm/remote machine

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a test scenario, where I load the html page and validate it for some css properties using selenium.
It works great on my local. Below is the code I use:

```
String inputFilePath = "src/main/java/elementspkg/fixtures/responsive.html";
String url = new File(inputFilePath).getAbsolutePath();
driver.get("file:///"+url);
```

Now I want to run the same test on a remote machine/vm for eg. SauceLabs. Now my test fails because the url that is launched on VM is the same as in my local.

I want to know to handle this scenario where my html file which is sitting in my project workspace, should always be invoked successfully irrespective of any remote machine that I run  my test?

Could somebody please help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Log when I run on my local:

url: file:////Users/aspiringqa/Desktop/javatests-travis-ci-poc/src/main/java/elementspkg/fixtures/responsive.html

Log when my test runs via Travis CI on Sauce Labs:
url: file:////home/travis/build/xxx/javatests-travis-ci-poc/src/main/java/elementspkg/fixtures/responsive.html

I guess what I need is to get the absolute path of the VM machine. Any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

What I did is, I spinned up a simple python server in the `before_script` tag in `.travis.yml` file

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

Passed url as:

```
String url="http://localhost:8000/src/main/java/elements/fixtures/responsive.html"

driver.get(url);
```

And it works awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Place the html file with-in automation project. e.g "project path/resources/html file" and give the generic path to pick the file.

Try

```
String inputFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/<html file>";
```

**Note**: "user.dir" is user working directory.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish.. However, I see no difference in the result. When I run on sauce labs from Travis CI, it simply pulls up the base dir from Travis. So this path will not work on the VM machine.